# Groupby one column and show distinct size on the other (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data where I would like to groupby one column and take the distinct size of the another column. I would like to keep both column titles and add a count column

data

```
Id  location
A.1 ny
A.2 ny
A   ny
A   ny
B   ca
B   ca
```

desired

```
Id  location  count 
A.1 ny        3
A.2 ny             
A   ny
B   ca        2
B   ca
```

doing

```
df.groupby('location')['Id'].size()
```

However, the output is not showing the titles and I am not sure how to add the Id column.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `groupby('location')['Id'].nunique()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you - is there a way to list the Id column name and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.assign(count=df.groupby('location').transform('nunique'))
```

Output:

```
    Id location  count
0  A.1       ny      3
1  A.2       ny      3
2    A       ny      3
3    A       ny      3
4    B       ca      1
5    B       ca      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the output was a list, I think you would either have [4, 2] or [3, 1] in your example.